# What is wrong with ARIMA model?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.9

I have to create ARIMA model script in order to forecast U.S GDP. Even though I tried t reinstall all the libraries and rewrite whole code it still does not work.I already asked question here and I was told that my values were wrong. I rechecked them and they are correct, but the code still doesn't work
And I alway get the same error: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1s8DdF_jANqtq6EFlUKgOykv6bpQ_4deUx13LvDIRCrk/edit